# Error using HttpClient in dotnet function

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to create an advert but everytime it gives an error at this line:

```
var response = await _client.PostAsync(new Uri($"{_baseAddress}/Create"),
                new StringContent(jsonModel, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I Added a breakpoint and it stops creating the response. Bellow is my function that i use

```
var advertApiModel = _mapper.Map<AdvertModel>(model);
var jsonModel = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(advertApiModel);
var response = await _client.PostAsync(new Uri($"{_baseAddress}/Create"),
            new StringContent(jsonModel, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).ConfigureAwait(false);
var createAdvertResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<CreateAdvertResponse>().ConfigureAwait(false);
var advertResponse = _mapper.Map<AdvertResponse>(createAdvertResponse);

return advertResponse;
```

The error that terminal outputs is:

```
    info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.IAdvertApiClient.LogicalHandler[100]
      Start processing HTTP request POST http://localhost:5000/adverts/v1/Create
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.IAdvertApiClient.LogicalHandler: Information: Start processing HTTP request POST http://localhost:5000/adverts/v1/Create
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.IAdvertApiClient.ClientHandler[100]
      Sending HTTP request POST http://localhost:5000/adverts/v1/Create
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.IAdvertApiClient.ClientHandler: Information: Sending HTTP request POST http://localhost:5000/adverts/v1/Create
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:5000/adverts/v1/Create application/json; charset=utf-8 76
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:5000/adverts/v1/Create application/json; charset=utf-8 76
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 5.2898000000000005ms 404
```

When I hover over var response after it passes it it shows this error:

```
{StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Fri, 17 Jan 2020 13:30:02 GMT
  Server: Kestrel
  Content-Length: 0
}}
```

Comment: What error your getting?

Comment: Please edit your question to include what the error is.

Comment: try to read response as string and then deserealize into `CreateAdvertResponse`

Comment: @Crowcoder I included more details

Comment: @demo How? I am following a course from udemy and even if i clone the guy source code, i keep on get same error and everything breaks at var response

Comment: ok, so your response cannot be converted into `CreateAdvertResponse`. that's all what I can understand.

Comment: 404 means that the url {_baseAddress}/Create is not found so something is wrong there. Can you confirm that the url http://localhost:5000/adverts/v1/Create is valid and exists?

Comment: @demo It won't even get there. It won't create response first. When it executes this line: var response = await _client.PostAsync(new Uri($"{_baseAddress}/Create"),
            new StringContent(jsonModel, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).ConfigureAwait(false);

Comment: @majita that command suppose to build that url. Is getting baseUrl from appsettings add /create and content as json to pass it

Comment: Does this url exist? http://localhost:5000/adverts/v1/Create

Comment: @majita no. how do i created? I thought httpClient will create it using new uri with baseAddress/create

Comment: If you are following a Udemy course it will likely have the code for that web application in there somewhere or it should tell you how to create and run it.

Comment: @majita it has it on github and i clone it but i keep on get same error, and instructor replies very late so nothing from him so far :(

Comment: Looks like the URI endpoint '/create' doesn't exist

Comment: @LinkedListT and that new Uri($"{_baseAddress}/Create" should create it no?

Comment: I mean, the resource you are trying to hit, is it active? It looks like it's run on your localhost. Resource not found seems like it cannot find this api.

Comment: @LinkedListT thanks for your help. I changed api server to localhost:5001 and run everything again but now i get an internal error. api seems to work fine and process request without issue but mvc give this error now. Any more suggestions, thanks: info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.IAdvertApiClient.ClientHandler[100]
      Sending HTTP request POST http://localhost:5001/adverts/v1/create
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.IAdvertApiClient.ClientHandler: Information: Sending HTTP request POST http://localhost:5001/adverts/v1/create